# Handling browser history when using ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html, browser-history

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC3 Application, and in a search page, I'm using ajax to get and update juste the result part of the page. The problem is with the browser history. For example, if the user is in the 5th page of the result, and then click on the browser refresh, he will get the index page (he should get the 5th page refreshed). same problem with the back button of the browser. I did some research, and I found the extension named [jQuery History](http://balupton.github.io/jquery-history/demo/#/coconuts). In their example, they are using the tabs system (hide and show), not the same situation as mine (pagination). Here is a simple of my code :

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**
I try to use the *Html 5 history API*, but it does not work using this code, I noteced using FireBug, that after the first page navigation (ex : to the page 2), the GET method is twice executed !!

**EDIT 2:**
When debugging, I noticed that when handling the `popstate` event, the `location.pathname` property has always `/Home/GoToPage`, but it should has for example `/Home/GoToPage?pageIndex=3`

**My index page**

```
<h2>Pages navigator</h2>      
@Html.Partial("_Result")
```

**My result partial view**

```
@model HistoryConcept.Models.Result

<aside id="content">
    @{
        var prevUrl = String.Format(@"/Home/GoToPage?pageIndex={0}", Model.PageNumber - 1);
        var nextUrl = String.Format(@"/Home/GoToPage?pageIndex={0}", Model.PageNumber + 1);

        <a id="goPrevious" href="@prevUrl">Previous page</a>
        <a id="goNext" href="@nextUrl">Next page</a> 
    }

    <div>Page number : @Model.PageNumber</div>
    <div>@Model.PageContent</div>
</aside>
```

**The javascript in the result partial view**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function (e) {
            getPage(location.pathname);
        });

        setupHistoryClicks();
    });

    function setupHistoryClicks() {
        addClicker($('#goPrevious'));
        addClicker($('#goNext'));
    }

    function addClicker(link) {

        link.click(function (e) {
            var linkHref = link.attr('href');
            getPage(linkHref);
            history.pushState(null, null, linkHref);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }

    function getPage(href) {

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", href, false);
        req.send(null);

        if (req.status == 200) {
            $('#content').replaceWith(req.responseText);
            setupHistoryClicks();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

**My controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new Result {PageContent = "This is the home page"};
            return View(model);
        }

        public PartialViewResult GoToPage(int pageIndex)
        {
            var model = new Result
                {
                    PageNumber = pageIndex,
                    PageContent = "New page content"
                };
            return PartialView("_Result", model);
        }
```

Comment: You may also want to look at the new HTML 5 history API. Pretty cool. But you'll still need hash tags to support older browsers. http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: why dont you use something like session to keep the current page number - this way when they refresh the page you can check in your ajax request the current session["page"] or similar to get the page they were on

Comment: @smdrager : Thanks for the idea, as I mentioned in the edit, I'm trying to use the Html 5 API, but it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

**Parameters for paging**

•Keeping page number in query string

In this approach, number of items per page is configured in server side. So page number 2 means it displays records from 11 to 20, but the issue is later if you decide to display 50 items per page, then page number 2 means 51 to 100.
This is wrong, always you URL should return same result, as your user may book marked, OR Search engines refers to specific page of your application for specific keywords.

•The best approach is, keep two parameters

Start : Start index
Count: number of items per page
So if start is 11 and number of records is 10, it displays 11 to 20 records.

With this the paging is purely controlled by UI, however make sure you have a maximum limit for count to avoid huge data load.
Paging using ajax
Store start, and count in #, on body load create first request based on # parameters.

**Session??**
Never implement paging logic using Session. A URL should have all the information to reload the same data. if user book marks page number 10, make sure you load the same page when the user visits the book mark,  This is what all user expects however this will not there in your business requirement document.